# SSD external drive with encrypted luks partition unmounts itself on high read write actions

Tags: pi-4, usb, mount, encryption

I wanted to make myself something like NAS with RPi4 4GB ram and 1TB SSD drive.
I have been using Nextcloud and now syncthing trying to accomplish that goal but in both cases I'm running into the same issue, my SSD external drive with encrypted luks partition unmounts itself on high read write actions (like synchronizing folder with large amount of items, lets say few GB), when that happens i'm just rebooting it and it goes back normal untill i load it again with files, it runs for like 1-2GB and unmounts itself again.
My raspberry have no cooling hat but it looks like it's not burning

```
##CPU temp readout
cpu=$(</sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp) 
echo “$((cpu/1000))C”
“25C”
```

So it looks like its cool, disk is also not hot, so i have no idea what's wrong
Partition looks fine and it's not having read write issues when i have that SSD connected to my regular computer so I assume there's something messed up on my raspberry setup (and yes, I'm using USB 3.0 port ;D).

dmesg:

```
[  282.634471] sd 0:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[  282.653954] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 8953200 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  282.654020] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 34824 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  282.654049] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 7899136 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  282.654076] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 27822080 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  282.654097] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 27826216 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  282.654111] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 28350488 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  282.654117] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 28084224 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  282.654143] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 3506176, lost async page write
[  282.654150] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 28351392 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
[  282.654178] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 3539573, lost async page write
[  282.654184] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 28088752 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  282.654203] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 3539574, lost async page write
[  282.654204] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 28088984 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  282.654222] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 3506771, lost async page write
[  282.654243] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 3539685, lost async page write
[  282.654256] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 3506774, lost async page write
[  282.654279] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 3539686, lost async page write
[  282.654286] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 3538944, lost async page write
[  282.654300] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 3539687, lost async page write
[  282.654329] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 3540583, lost async page write
[  282.654813] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_check_bdev_write_error:218: comm syncthing: Error while async write back metadata
[  282.655317] Aborting journal on device dm-0-8.
[  282.655479] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_journal_check_start:83: comm syncthing: Detected aborted journal
[  282.655553] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_journal_check_start:83: comm syncthing: Detected aborted journal
[  282.655753] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_journal_check_start:83: comm syncthing: Detected aborted journal
[  282.655848] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_journal_check_start:83: comm syncthing: Detected aborted journal
[  282.656170] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_journal_check_start:83: comm syncthing: Detected aborted journal
[  282.656214] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  282.657806] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for dm-0-8.
[  282.663300] EXT4-fs (dm-0): previous I/O error to superblock detected
[  282.665235] EXT4-fs (dm-0): I/O error while writing superblock
[  282.665235] EXT4-fs (dm-0): I/O error while writing superblock
[  282.665264] EXT4-fs (dm-0): Remounting filesystem read-only
[  282.670137] EXT4-fs (dm-0): I/O error while writing superblock
[  282.671350] EXT4-fs (dm-0): previous I/O error to superblock detected
[  282.671695] EXT4-fs (dm-0): I/O error while writing superblock
[  282.689972] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```

Any clues?

Comment: "Partition looks fine" - hardly the filesystem is corrupt.

Comment: You need to show earlier msg messages,  My guess is that the USB bus has reset under load, I have seen this on several different  devices when they are connected to  the USB 3 ports when the load is high (Ethernet, BulkIO Devices etc).  Try using the USB2 ports to see if it is more stable.